# Rewrite multiple occurence of a term in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to convert all the `&amp;` in my URL to `&` :

Here is my URL : `https://test.com/index.php?option=com_media&amp;task=file.upload&amp;tmpl=component&amp;820470bdbcec556c83a51cb33ca92922=kfp1tif94iuetenuab6hfi5mvd&amp;690012fb504cea7eee8475c0963a8fc4=1&amp;asset=image&amp;format=json`

and here is what I try to achieve :

`https://test.com/index.php?option=com_media&task=file.upload&tmpl=component&820470bdbcec556c83a51cb33ca92922=kfp1tif94iuetenuab6hfi5mvd&690012fb504cea7eee8475c0963a8fc4=1&asset=image&format=json`

So far I've tried the following rules :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(&amp;)(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&%3 [N,L,R=301]
```

But it's only replacing the last `&amp;`

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: How are you getting `&amp;` in your URL?

Comment: @anubhava It's caused by an external plugin that I can't edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules for replacing all `&amp;` with `&`. Note that there will only single redirect in the end:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# recursively replace &amp; with &
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)&amp;(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&%2 [N,DPI,E=done:1]

# redirect in the end
RewriteCond %{ENV:done} =1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !&amp; [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !&amp; [NC]` can you explain this line please ? Also what do you mean by that there will only single redirect in the end ?

Comment: That condition means execute last redirect rule if query string doesn't have `&amp;` in it. `NC` is for ignore case match